# highcharts JoeKuan set title

Tags: highcharts, extjs4

i m using highcharts JoeKuan, but i have tried set title, all failed.

JoeKuan HighCharts : https://github.com/JoeKuan/Highcharts_Sencha/

a lot of example i have tried, maybe JoeKuan's High Chart set title is bug?

this is the example i have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-settitle/

```
chart.setTitle({
    text: 'New title ' + i++
});
```

Error : `TypeError: chart.setTitle is not a function`

or

```
chart.options.subtitle.text = 'Sales';
```

or

```
chart.title = "a"
```

any idea?

Comment: Did you look at [this page](http://joekuan.org/demos/Highcharts_Sencha/docs/#!/api/Chart.ux.Highcharts-method-setTitle)? Maybe you should try `chart.setTitle('New title ' + i++);`.

Comment: So please contact with the wrapper's author.